# societal issues vs social issues

Tags: translation

I am trying to translate the French phrase "questions de société".  We use it when we speak of issues broader than just social issues ( workers, unemployment, poverty...). "Questions de société" also includes issues about evolution of society, cultural identity...

I found the phrase "societal issues" in some English text translated from French but this term doesn't come up in google search.

Is there another term for societal issues?

Comment: In the U.S., a well-known radio talk show host likes to boast that he is "on the cutting edge of societal evolution," to the point where it's almost cliché. I think _societal evolution_ would be a valid term for _social issues_ in many contexts, but you might want to avoid it in the U.S. if you don't want to be associated with what [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Rush_Limbaugh_Show) calls "his schtick of .. giving himself accolades with phrases praising his own performance," such as _Talent on loan from God,_ and _Half my brain tied behind my back, just to make it fair._

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two words are synonymous, and either phrasing could be used, although [Google's Ngram tool](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=societal%20issues%2Csocial%20issues%2Csocietal%20evolution%2Csocial%20evolution&year_start=1920&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3) shows that *social issues* seems to be the predominant term.

I wouldn't go so far as to say the two words are always interchangeable. At least in the U.S., students go to college majoring in *social work*, not *societal work*. In the context of social issues, though, *social issues* may be more common, but that doesn't mean it's always more correct.

Perhaps a good follow-on to your question would be: When might one be preferable over the other? I think *social* would almost always be a safe bet, but I can think of one reason *societal* might be preferred in some contexts – a narrower definition. According to NOAD, *societal* means:

> **societal** (*adj.*) of or relating to society or social relations : *societal change*.

The word *social* has pretty much the exact same meaning, although its meaning does seem to be subtly broader:

> **social** (*adj.*) of or relating to society or its organization : *a major social problem* | *a traditional Japanese social structure*.
> • of or relating to rank and status in society : *a recent analysis of social class in Britain*
> • needing companionship and therefore best suited to living in communities : *we are social beings as well as individuals*

One ["Writing Tips" website](http://www.dailywritingtips.com/social-vs-societal/) says that the two are pretty much synonymous, although *societal* might sound more pompous outside of a formal academic setting:

> *societal* appeared in the latter part of the nineteenth century as a more serious, scholarly alternative. It is mostly seen in such usage and is otherwise considered pretentious.

The question was also [asked on ELU](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/45498/difference-between-social-and-societal) a few years ago; I think Neil Coffey's comment there sums it up pretty well:

> if there's any confusion, "societal" allows you to disambiguate – it is probably for this reason that it is reasonably common in academic writing.

Imagine you were organizing a conference, and you were considering two titles:

- International Conference on Societal Change
- International Conference on Social Change

The latter title would work if the conference intended to address issues like poverty, unemployment, or substance abuse. The former seems to have a more narrow focus; specifically, a more academic view on how society is evolving.

Then again, maybe I'm just reading too much into it.

Back to your original question:

> I am trying to translate the French phrase *questions de société*. We use it when we speak of issues broader than just social issues (workers, unemployment, poverty...). *Questions de société* also includes issues about evolution of society, cultural identity...

English works pretty much the same way. *Social issues* may often refer to broader problems like unemployment and poverty, as well as cultural identity, while *societal issues* can also apply to both. However, the surrounding context (such as the title of a conference) might create an initial impression in one direction or another.